# How to create a loop that adds html elements and increments css properties upon creation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Im essentially trying to create loop that will fill up this black background with bricks using javascript, I assume that I will need to create a loop that adds html elements and increments the left: css property by 100px, as well as adding on .5 seconds onto the animation delay for each element created.
heres an example of the animation using css and html. Any ideas that could help would be appreciated.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.brick {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: white 2px solid;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  animation: brick-lay 1s ease-in;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.place {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border: white 2px solid;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  animation: brick-lay 1.5s ease-in;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.brick1 {
  left: 100px;
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

@keyframes brick-lay {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(450px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brick place"></div>
    <div class="brick1 place"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Given what you're showing: why would it need to increment `left` by 100px each time? Just make your boxes `display:inline-block` and they'll line up in their parent just fine? Similarly, why add time to the CSS animation? Just create the elements on an interval instead (or preallocate them with a hidden class, and then set their real class on an interval) Having said that, Stackoverflow is [not an idea board](/help/how-to-ask); if you don't know how to get started yet, SO is not the right place to ask. Once you've written some code and you get stuck, _that's_ the time to consider posting to SO

Comment: Okay, my apologies, thank you for the advice, I shall conduct more research on my own.